# How can I post Yammer's Poll using the REST API?

Tags: java, rest, post, yammer

I am trying to create a java app that posts Poll with Yammer using the REST API.

When I set ‍`poll‍‍‍‍` to `message_type` and POST `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages` but status `400 Bad Request` is returned.

```
// Post
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages");
// Add header
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessAuthToken);

 List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<>();
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("group_id", group));
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", "message body 1"));
 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message_type", "poll"));

// set entity
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, UTF8));
// execute
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

How can I post Poll using the REST API?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked about how to post a poll via the REST API, and the answer at this time is that it's not supported. I wish I had a better answer, but this isn't documented on the Yammer Developer site and it's a risk for you (and your users) to attempt to reverse engineer it for inclusion in an app.

If you were to reverse engineer it, capture a Fiddler trace with your current code, and then tweak the HTTP request until it matches the Yammer site.

If you want an API supported then you should post on the [Yammer UserVoice](https://yammer.uservoice.com/) site. So many requests for things end in threads like this and it would be better if the visibility was raised.

Comment: Hi Brian!
Thanks for your reply.

I understood.
Why I can not find an answer even by examining the Web.
And I can not find a solution by post poll there.

I will explore other alternatives.